# how to get sum of integer value from recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i am want to implement something like invoice. i am using recyclerview in fragment. and textview. i have some item in recyclerview. which content title,unit and price. now i want to get sum of all item's price in my textview which is in fragment. here is image what i want to achive.

here is image for understanding

[image]

here is my code for adapter class

```
public class Checkout_fragment2_confermation_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Checkout_fragment2_confermation_Adapter.ViewHolder>  {

static List<Cart_datamodel> data;
static Context context;

public Checkout_fragment2_confermation_Adapter(Context context , List<Cart_datamodel> data1) {
    data = new ArrayList<Cart_datamodel>();
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data1;
}


@Override
public Checkout_fragment2_confermation_Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.checkout_fragmet2confermation_listviwe_single_row, null);
    itemLayoutView.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    Checkout_fragment2_confermation_Adapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new Checkout_fragment2_confermation_Adapter.ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Checkout_fragment2_confermation_Adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.title.setText(data.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.price.setText(data.get(position).getPrice());
    holder.product_img.setImageBitmap(getImage(data.get(position).getImg()));


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView  title,price;
    public ImageView img,product_img;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_checkout_fgment2);
        price =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.price_checkout_fragment2);
        product_img =(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_checkout_fragment2);
    }
}
public static Bitmap getImage(byte[] image) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
}

}
```

here is my fragment class

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab2, container, false);

    dataBaseAdapter = new AddressDataBaseAdapter(getContext());
    cart_adapter = new Item_adding_cart(getContext());
    dbList = cart_adapter.getDataFromDB();

   // listview = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listview);

    recyclerView =(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view_checkout_fgrment2);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    recycleradapter = new Checkout_fragment2_confermation_Adapter(getContext(),dbList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recycleradapter);



    fname =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.firstname_conformation);
    lname =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lastname_conformation);
    mobile =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.mobile_conformaton);
    address =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.address_conformation);
    zipcode =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.zipcode_conformation);
    city =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.city_conformation);




    addresslist= new ArrayList<Address_Activity_DataModel>();
    addresslist=dataBaseAdapter.getDataFromDB();

    int count = dataBaseAdapter.getrowcount();
    if(count==0){

    }
    else
    {
        showRecords();
    }

   // loaddata();



    return view;

}
```

Comment: onBindViewHolder check position and list size equal then add total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fragment, just iterate through your dbList before/after you add it to your adapter.

```
int totalPrice = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<dbList.size(); i++)
{
    totalPrice += dbList.get(i).getPrice();
}
```

I don't suggest you calculate anything in the adapter's onBindView because onBindView won't be called for views that are not loaded and it will be called multiple times.

Comment: thanks. brother. its working fine. and so simply i achived what i wanted. thanks again

Comment: what happens if user have thousands of product ?

Comment: Nothing that shouldn't happen. The solution still works. In worst case scenario, it won't fit in an int, but don't think that would be the case when talking about a price.

Answer (score 2):

### just count the amount of your recyclerview list and multiply by the value to get the perfect sum inside, i the fragment

```
List<ItemPurchase> item = new ArrayList<>();             
int total = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < items.size; i++){
    total = total + items.get(i).price()}

 t.setText(String.valueOf( total));
```

**This function in kotlin**

```
var total = 0;
            for ( i in 0 until  myDebt.size){
                total += myDebt[i].valueAdp
            }
```

this is the method you need to implement to get the grand total price. can call this method within your activity
 and you can still assign the value to textView.

```
 mtv_my_debt.setText(String.valueOf(total))
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I have similar answer to @Adrian-Alexandru Coman beause the method to calculate the sum is the same.
I believe your Total Amount is just a TextView with in the fragment,as that's what the image shows. So first you define a method in the Fragment to calculate the sum. 
Assuming that you have an instance variable of arraylist and a Entity Class(POJO)that holds your arraylist data :

> Suppose your arraylist is foodList and entity class is Foods.Then you
>   have an arraylist like below:

```
ArrayList<Foods> foodList
```

then,the method will be:

```
public void getSumofAllitems(){
int total_sum=0;
for(int i=0;i<foodList.size();i++){
Foods food_items=foodList.get(i);
int price=food_items.getPrice();//getPrice() is a getter method in your POJO class. 
total_sum+= price;
}
totalpriceTextView.setText(total_sum+"");
}
```

Then from your RecyclerView's onBindViewHolder method,check the posiion of the view that is:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Checkout_fragment2_confermation_Adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.title.setText(data.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.price.setText(data.get(position).getPrice());
    holder.product_img.setImageBitmap(getImage(data.get(position).getImg()));
if(position==data.size()-1){
((Activity)context).getSumofAllitems();
}
}
```

I called the method from RecyclerView  and checked the position so that the method won't be executed util all your views are bind to RecyclerView and the RecycleView is populated. I believe this is the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following show your total count view only if last element

```
  int total=0;
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Checkout_fragment2_confermation_Adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.title.setText(data.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.price.setText(data.get(position).getPrice());
        holder.product_img.setImageBitmap(getImage(data.get(position).getImg()));
    total+=data.get(position).getPrice();

    if(position==data.size()-1){//check if list last element
    //show your total count view here---- and add total amount
    }

}
```

Comment: Think of the situation where you will have 50 items and you start scrolling all the way down and up again? In a RecyclerView, you will get the same item price added multiple times because onBind will be called multiple times for the same item.

Comment: @Adrian-AlexandruComan if your position ==0 then set total item price=0

Comment: But then I won't have the total correct price. It will be 0, though I have items in the RV. Notice that the 'total amount' view isn't in the RV.

Comment: add a total price when view binding check if list in last position  add total

Answer (score -1):

you should chnge your onBindViewHolder as below:

```
  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Checkout_fragment2_confermation_Adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.title.setText(data.get(position).getTitle());
    if (position == dat.size()) {
        holder.price.setText(getTotalPrice());
    } else
        holder.price.setText(data.get(position).getPrice());
    holder.product_img.setImageBitmap(getImage(data.get(position).getImg()));

}

public int getTotalPrice() {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        total+=data.get(i);
    }
    return total;
}
```

if your total price is not changing again you can calculate the total price at first and for once.